# Error: "Decoding error (36) : Dictionary mismatch" using ZSTD decode on command line to decode a .ZST file

Tags: encryption, compression, zstandard, zstd

I am trying to decode a bunch of .ZST files which I do not know what the original file was so I can access them, however all of the .ZSTs return the exact same error and do not get decompressed. The error is `Decoding error (36) : Dictionary mismatch`. The command used is `zstd -d *` on Windows 10 x64 using ZSTD v1.4.4 for Win x64.

I have already tried CMD, PowerShell and Bash as different environments to run the command but all return the exact same error. I have tried decompressing a single individual file to see if it was a bulk-operation issue but it didn't work either. My last attempt was to Google for the error but I could not find anything.

Edit: After investigating a little further, I decided to try checking for the MIME types of my ZST files, some of them get returned as `application/x-zstd` while others get returned as `application/octet-stream`. I wonder if this could be the issue? Although neither MIME types work, both return the same error.

Does anyone know how I could fix this error and get to decompress my files?

Here is one of the ZST files for reference: https://mega.nz/#!eV0VTKBQ!WBW_pVIq8Tsn2Rrv3XKmt4DSAH7IHbHtaAuNB9uRTMQ

Comment: I guess those files were compressed [using an external dictionary](https://facebook.github.io/zstd/#small-data). If that's the case, you need to provide the same dictionary for decompression as well.